# Chrome app window cannot be moved partially outside of screen using moveTo

Tags: google-chrome-app

When a Chrome app window is moved to the edge of the screen using the mouse, the window can be moved partially outside of the screen.

[image]

However when trying to move a Chrome app window beyond the screen using the `moveTo` function it remains snapped to the edge of the screen.

[image]

Is there any other method which can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using setBounds() instead of moveTo(), that works for me:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'bounds': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 500
    }
  }, function(appwindow) {
     appwindow.setBounds({left: -200, top: 200, width: 400, height: 500});
  });
});
```

You don't even need to pass the width and height back:

```
appwindow.setBounds({ left: -200, top: 200 });
```

And to get the AppWindow object outside of the create() callback, use:

```
var appwindow = chrome.app.window.current();
```