# How to move a window after restart with the window API for chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

As mentioned here:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create

If you use ID's for you windows (as you need if you don't like to start you app twice) the position an size is getting stored. And they advice you to create the window hidden an move and re-size it before showing.

If I try to create a window on a particular screen like this:

```
var left =  parseInt(displayInfo.workArea.left);

chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
      id: 'window-'+displayInfo.id,
      hidden: true,
      bounds: {left: left, top: 0, width: 100 , height: 100  }
, callbackWindow.bind(null, left, 0, displayInfo));

var callbackWindow = function (left, top, displayInfo, createdWindow) {
    createdWindow.moveTo(displayInfo.workArea.left, displayInfo.workArea.top);
    console.log(createdWindow.id, createdWindow.getBounds());
    createdWindow.show();
};
```

The first time the application starts the window is on the correct position, now if we move the window and re-size it and then restart the app. The stay on the same potion as before closing.

In other words, we can not override the stored position. Is this a Bug or should it work like this?

I've made my tests on Windows 7 with Chrome 32.0.1700.107 dev-m

Comment: Don't "beg bugs" in titles. Simply ask the question and state the observed behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

moveTo is the standard DOM moveTo. The AppWindow object just forwards moveTo and resizeTo functions to the window object.

What happens if you try to use the AppWindow.setBounds instead? I'm guessing, but haven't tested, that the DOM functions are being ignored as the window is not visible.

Also, you are using a fairly old version of Chrome. I think the current stable version is 34.

Comment: This works, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561502/chrome-app-window-cannot-be-moved-partially-outside-of-screen-using-moveto

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is a bit unclear on how `moveTo` should be called.

Please try the following format instead, in line with other parametrized calls:

```
createdWindow.moveTo({
    left: displayInfo.workArea.left,
    top: displayInfo.workArea.top
});
```

Comment: also `createdWindow.resizeTo({width: 150, height: 150});` or `createdWindow.resizeTo(150, 150);` do not have any effect on a restart.